# ConTeXt: Change emphasis font when used within blockquote environment

Tags: fonts, environments, context, emphasis

## Background

Looking to change the font for emphasized text within a specific type of macro block (environment). Only emphasized text should change; any text within the environment that is not emphasized should not be affected.

The text is written in Markdown, such as:

```
> _This is text in a blockquote environment._

This is a paragraph that also includes *emphasized* text.

> This text is also in a blockquote environment.
```

Pandoc generates the following ConTeXt fragment:

```
\startblockquote
{\em This is text in a blockquote environment.}
\stopblockquote

This is a paragraph that also includes {\em emphasized} text.

\startblockquote
This text is also in a blockquote environment.
\stopblockquote
```

## Problem

Because the text is generated, the ConTeXt fragment cannot be changed. I would like to produce a document that resembles:

[image: Example Output]

Note how the font for the emphasized text in the first blockquote environment differs from italicized text. Also note how the second blockquote environment has a different font than the first environment.

## Question

How would you change the font marked up using `{\em ...}`, but only if it occurs inside a `blockquote` environment (using ConTeXt mkiv)?

Comment: You can define two typefaces (or two font families) and add `\setupdelimitedtext[blockquote][style={\switchtobodyfont[other]}]`.

Comment: In your last example you mention that you also want the "block quote regular font" to change from Times New Roman to Liberation Serif. That would imply changing the entire blockquote style

Comment: Just to be sure, if the block quote contains some italic text `{\it ...}` and some emphasized text `{\em ...}`, you want the emphasized text to come out differently from the italic text. Is it okay to use a macro `\emph{...}` instead of a font switch `{\em ...}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the style of `\em` using the `\setupbodyfontenvironment` command.

```
\setupdelimitedtext
  [blockquote]
  [before={\setupbodyfontenvironment[default][em=mono]}]

\starttext

\startblockquote
{\em This is text in a blockquote environment.}
\stopblockquote

This is a paragraph that also includes {\em emphasized} text.

\startblockquote
This text is also in a blockquote environment.
\stopblockquote

\stoptext
```

Comment: Can this method be used to change to a font other than `mono` (e.g., if we want italic from a different fontface)?

Comment: @Aditya No you can’t use the `em` key to use a font from a different typeface because this was only a simple extension to `\em` for a user who wanted coloured text as result of the command.

Answer (score 3):

Aditya has provided the elements to an answer, so all kudos to him. Here's what I would suggest (hoping I have understood your question).

```
\setupbodyfontenvironment[default][em=italic]

\starttypescript [serif] [blockfont] [name]
  \definefontsynonym [Serif]          [file:texgyretermes-regular]
  \definefontsynonym [SerifItalic]    [file:texgyrepagella-italic][rscale=0.9]
 \stoptypescript

\starttypescript [blockfont]
  \definetypeface [blockfont] [rm] [serif] [blockfont] [default] 
\stoptypescript 

\usetypescript [blockfont]
\setupbodyfont [termes]

\setupdelimitedtext[blockquote][style={\switchtobodyfont[blockfont]}]

\starttext

\startblockquote
  Blockquote environment with {\em emphasized} text. 
\stopblockquote

Regular environment with {\em emphasized} text. 

\stoptext
```

[image]

This uses TeX Gyre Pagella as the italic font inside the block-quote environment, and TeX Gyre Termes as the italic font ouside the block-quote environment. You can notice the difference if you look closely at the above figure (compare the `p` and the `z`). This should also work with the newfangled font selection mechanism instead of the old approach with a typescript, but I ran into problems and reverted to this method.

Comment: Metafox's solution is cleaner than mine, so just disregard it. However, blockquote is defined in the context core. I don't know if that will create problems.